# informatica min and max value dynamically fetch from database

Tags: dynamic, parameters, max, min, informatica

I have a requirement to fetch records from a table in oracle database with the id in search condition .I need to take min and max value of the id and need to compare against another table and store the missing id .This need to be done on a daily basis and the current run max value will become the min value of next day run.

Kindly let me know how to achieve the get the min and max value as parameter in Informatica and assign on  daily basis

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic options:
- store those in a file
- use mapping/workflow variable combination. Use persistent WF variables, do a Pre-session var assignment, set new values in the mapping, do a post-session var assignment to store values in workflow variables.
Let me know if you'd have any issues.

Answer (score 0):

same topic was discussed here  https://network.informatica.com/thread/38783 where the following detailed blog http://informatica-kareem.blogspot.in/2012/11/change-data-capture-cdc.html outlines all your options (incuding saved session variables). For future reference, what you're referring to is commonly  called incremental load and CDC.